# ssl certificate verification in pychef

Tags: python, ssl, chef-infra, pychef

I am trying to use python to connect to chef api. I am using [pychef](http://pychef.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api.html) to connect to chef from python.

Following are the code:

```
import chef
with chef.ChefAPI('https://chef-e.xxxx.com:443/organizations/xxxx', '/root/.chef/rajgourav.pem', 'rajgourav'):
    n = chef.Node('chef-e.xxxx.com')
```

I am getting following certificate error:

```
[root@chef-e py]# /appl/python27/bin/python  mychef.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mychef.py", line 6, in <module>
n = chef.Node('chef-e.xxxx.com')
File "/appl/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/chef/base.py", line 58, in __init__
data = self.api[self.url]
File "/appl/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/chef/api.py", line 229, in __getitem__
return self.api_request('GET', path)
File "/appl/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/chef/api.py", line 225, in api_request
response = self.request(method, path, headers, data)
File "/appl/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/chef/api.py", line 208, in request
response = self._request(method, self.url+path, data, dict((k.capitalize(), v) for k, v in request_headers.iteritems()))
File "/appl/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/chef/api.py", line 195, in _request
return urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
File "/appl/python27/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/appl/python27/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/appl/python27/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
'_open', req)
File "/appl/python27/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/appl/python27/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
context=self._context)
File "/appl/python27/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)>
```

Could you please help me resolve ssl certificate error. I know I have to accept the certificate and add it to trusted certificate list but dont know how to do it in python.

P.S. I am able to work with knife without any issue.

I tried using  ssl_verify param but I am getting error :

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ssl_verify'
```

from api.py:

```
def __init__(self, url, key, client, version='0.10.8', headers={}):
```

Some info about my env :

```
[root@chef-e py]# /appl/python27/bin/python 
Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug  8 2015, 06:25:19) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> import chef
 >>> chef.__version__
 (0, 2, 3, 'dev')
 >>>
```

Thanks,
Rajgourav Jain

Comment: I've also updated my answer to reflect your edit.

Answer (score 2):

The [__init__ method of ChefAPI](https://github.com/coderanger/pychef/blob/527064846d220ff3e35a69949cc4c490b462db9d/chef/api.py#L59) has the following signature:

```
def __init__(self, url, key, client, version='0.10.8', headers={}, ssl_verify=True):
```

So obviously, you have to set the parameter `ssl_verify` to `False`:

```
import chef
with chef.ChefAPI(
  'https://chef-e.xxxx.com:443/organizations/xxxx',
  '/root/.chef/rajgourav.pem',
  'rajgourav',
  ssl_verify=False):
```

But indeed, this is still missing in the [documentation](http://pychef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

EDIT: indeed, this seems to be a change that is not yet released (the [v0.2.3 tag](https://github.com/coderanger/pychef/blob/v0.2.3/chef/api.py#L73) does not yet contain this option). So either use the source from the master branch or nag the author to push out a new release.

Comment: What about fixing the trusting of the certificate instead of disabling the validation ? Can't python take advantage of the SSL_CERT_FILE environment variable (or be given a list of CA ?). This mean adding the self-signed cert to this list, [my answer about adding certs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604784/chef-berkshelf3-proxy-settings-windows-platform/25605415#25605415)

Comment: Sure, that might be the better way. I haven't used pychef so I'm not aware of the exact details.

Comment: According to the stacktrace it's matter of urllib2, not doing python myself I was just giving the idea in case you already had to deal with it ;)

Comment: Did this help to resolve the issue or did you find another way?

Comment: I think there's confusion, or you did comment on your own post instead of question :)